# How to remove index.php in codeigniter?, I have tried normal techniques, but didn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have started a `codeigniter` project and it works fine. But I cant access to the functions that I created in controller. All I need id to remove the `index.php` file. I have removed it from `config.php` and created a `.htaccess` file and wrote codes needed. But it's not reflecting

Here is my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed')
class EduApp_Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
public function first_message()
{
    $this->load->view('first_message');
}
}
```

And my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'EduApp_Controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/EduApp/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried different ways but none worked for me. Can anyone help me? 
It works fine when I try with following url

`http://localhost/EduApplication/index.php/Web_controller/first_message`

Comment: Make sure you are running Apache, `mod_rewrite` is installed and Apache is set up to read `.htaccess` files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983374/htaccess-mod-rewrite-not-working-in-subdirectory refer this

Comment: @kerbholz I am sure that appache is running, `mod_rewrite` is green ticked in appache modules. Both this didn't solve my issue

Comment: whats the error you are facing let us know what is the error !